# retrieve data from vuejs in looping php

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

hy I have code like this:

```js
this.$http.get(domain + id, function (data) {
                  console.log(data)
                   this.$set('editData', data)
              })
```

I know retrieve data in vuejs like this

```
<span v-for="editData in editData">{{editData.name}}</span>
```

but my quetion is:
what I can retrieve data in looping php for example I want to do like this :

```
<?php foreach($editData as $editData){your data}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what i understand in your question, you want to return a list of your data. you need to have an array container.

```
<?php 
$arr = [];
foreach($editData as $editData){
$arr[] = $editData;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: hy @jay temp thanks for your answer, but not working for me error" Undefined variable:editData